# How to send text from JTextFields to mysql database

Tags: mysql

Whenever I run this code it says java.sql.SQLException: Column 's' not found.
Can anyone help me out with this problem.I had already checked about the same problem in stack overflow but I couldn't find the solution.

```
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
    import java.util.Scanner;
    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.sql.*;
public class project extends JFrame
{
        static JLabel label1;
        static JLabel label2;
        static JLabel label3;
        static JLabel label4;
        static JButton b2;
        static JTextField text1;
        static JTextField text2;
        static JTextField text3;
    public static void main(String [] args)
        {

            JFrame F= new JFrame();
            JPanel P = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0,1));
            F.add(P);
            P.add(new JLabel("NAME"));
            text1=new JTextField();
            P.add(text1);
            P.add(new JLabel("ADDRESS"));
            text2=new JTextField();
            P.add(text2);
            P.add(new JLabel("AGE"));
            text3=new JTextField();
            P.add(text3);
            P.add(new JLabel("GENDER"));
            b2=new JButton("Submit");
            P.add(b2);
            //Code for functioning 'Submit' button
            b2.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){ 

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                    try
                    {

                    Connection C= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/first","root","root");   
                    Statement S=C.createStatement();
                    ResultSet R=S.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM demo");
                    while(R.next())
                    {
                        String s=text1.getText();
                        String s1=text2.getText();
                        String s2=text3.getText();
                        System.out.println(R.getString("s"));
                        System.out.println(R.getString("s1"));
                        System.out.println(R.getString("s2"));
                    }
                    }
                    catch(Exception ea)
                    {
                System.out.println(ea);     
                    }

                }

            });


            F.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
            F.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            F.setSize(400,750);
            F.setVisible(true);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Please tell us the database schema of your `demo` table.

Comment: CREATE TABLE demo (name VARCHAR(20), address VARCHAR(100), age VARCHAR(10), Password VARCHAR(20), Gender VARCHAR(10), education VARCHAR(20), department VARCHAR(20);

Comment: INSERT into demo VALUES ('sairam', '3151', '22', '12345', 'male', 'masters', 'computers');

Answer (score 0):

Instead of printing the values from the `ResultSet`, you can do this:

```
text1.setText(R.getString("s"));
text2.setText(R.getString("s1"));
text3.setText(R.getString("s2"));
```

But if there are list of values from the query, you code should be like this:

```
StringBuffer field1 = new StringBuffer();
StringBuffer field2 = new StringBuffer();
StringBuffer field3 = new StringBuffer();

while(R.next())
{   
    field1.append(R.getString("s") + "\n");
    field2.append(R.getString("s1") + "\n");
    field3.append(R.getString("s2") + "\n");
}

text1.setText(field1);
text2.setText(field2));
text3.setText(field3);
```

Comment: Sir when I made this changes it shows an error in the last three lines of the above code as field1, field2 and field3 cannot resolved into a variable.

Comment: try to make it like this: `text1.setText(field1.toString());`

Comment: Still the problem is same. I think there are some problems with my database queries. Can you please check my database query. CREATE TABLE demo (name VARCHAR(20), address VARCHAR(100), age VARCHAR(10), Password VARCHAR(20), Gender VARCHAR(10), education VARCHAR(20), department VARCHAR(20);
     
INSERT into demo VALUES ('sairam', '3151', '22', '12345', 'male', 'masters', 'computers');

Comment: what are those queries for? please update it in the origianal question with what you need

Comment: I have created a table using this queries and I tried sending the data from JTextFields into the table and finally it says cannot find column 's'.

Comment: we cannot solve this issue here using these comments, sorry my friend. You can open new question to fix it

Comment: you can put the new question here, and i'll answer

Comment: I did it successfully with the help of this statement    S.executeUpdate("insert into demo(name,address) values('"+s+"','"+s1+"')");                Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: you can vote up and mark it's a good answer if you would like to